# Проверить, что Webelement Select загрузил все опции

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Привет всем, случай следующий:
имеем следующий элемент на сайте Select в который элементы загружаются после нажатия на кнопку (post code look up).
Если после нажатия на кнопку я пытаюсь выбрать рандомный элемент или выбрать по индексу, падает ошибка:

```
org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: Element not found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it was looked up
```

Я сделал, так:

1. Жду пока впринципе появится дроп даун через

   wait.until()
2. Циклом перебираю уже подгруженные элементы, чтобы обождать подгрузку других.
   И так вроде бы работает, но хотелось бы найти лучший вариант.

Спасибо!

P.S.: Лоудера не было найдено

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После ajax загрузки элементы меняются, DOM перестраивается и старые элементы удаляются (это фишка браузера, а не selenium) Храните не сам элемент, а его Xpath и/или ID, либо другой набор атрибутов, позволяющий однозначно идентифицировать тот или иной элемент на странице. А поиск элемента для манипуляции с ним (клик, установка значения и тд.) можете выполнять непосредственно перед использованием. Т.е. вам необходимо иметь массив с набором атрибутов и/или Xpath и уже перебирая его, взаимодействовать с элементами.

Comment: Я использую PageFactory, и хотелось бы минимизировать случаи описанный вами как решение - хранить xpath. Других вариантов нет?)